# Enforcing a 15 minute idle timeout with AWS Cognito on a website

Tags: .net-core, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito to authenticate users on my ASPNET Core website. Users can sign-up, sign-in, and sign-out OK.

However I would like to automatically sign-out users if they do not interact with the site for 15 minutes.

I have managed to set things up so that the user is logged out of the website after 15 minutes by expiring the site cookies. However, the user is them immediately bounced to Cognito which signs them back in without asking for credentials and sends them back to my site. So for all intents and purposes they haven't been signed out at all.

Relevant code for that:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1); // Reset to 15
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.NonceCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
    options.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
         
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    ...
```

I am going to try setting the Cognito refresh token expiry down to the minimum of 1 hour, but that is rather longer than the 15 minutes I would like even if it does work. (Setting the access and id token expiry to 5 minutes doesn't do anything as they are automatically refreshed when they expire).

So far the options I've come up with are:

1. Set a timer in my web app that resets on activity. If the timer reaches 0 then use a Cognito API to either [revoke the refresh token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-revocation.html) or do a [global signout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GlobalSignOut.html) (this Cognito pool is only used for this single app so a global signout shouldn't cause issues).
2. Whenever the user requests a page check the time since they last viewed a page and if it's more than 15 minutes redirect them to the Cognito logout page.

Option 1 seems pretty fiddly and error prone. Option 2 can probably be worked around by a determined attacker as it requires the browser to do something (go to the Cognito site) before the user is logged out.

Is there an easier 3rd way of doing this?

**Edit:** This, from the [GlobalSignOut documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CognitoIdentityProvider/MCognitoIdentityProviderGlobalSignOutGlobalSignOutRequest.html) makes me think that even if I do implement GlobalSignOut or revoke refresh token the user will just get automatically signed back in for up to an hour:

> Signs out users from all devices. It also invalidates all refresh tokens that Amazon Cognito has issued to a user. A user can still use a hosted UI cookie to retrieve new tokens for the duration of the 1-hour cookie validity period.

This question appears to be from someone that has effectively tried option 1 and found that the 1 hour Cognito hosted UI cookies do indeed still log the user back in: [Amazon AWS Cognito Cookie Authentication from Stored Cookie -- .NET Core 3.1 C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75857501/amazon-aws-cognito-cookie-authentication-from-stored-cookie-net-core-3-1-c-s#comment135101492_75857501)